# What are u use in project with django.contrib.auth.models user

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

I wanna ask what u do when wanna create more than just name passwod and password_confirm .
Like "from django.contrib.auth.models  import Abstractuser
class name model(Abstractuser):" and add fields what u need or use "user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models. CASCADE) " in other model,and if u can pls explain which method and why.`Cause i can`t find this on documentation(if u can just send me link with this topic)

i don`t know which method better and don`t understand difference

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i said i wanna know which method better use model Abstractuser and in settings "AUTH_USER_MODEL  =   ’testapp.models.AdvUser ’"
or use One to One in other model

Answer (score 0):

You can lean on the official django site to find out
`django.contrib.auth.models`
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/auth/

About relationship "one to one".A one-to-one relationship in a relational database occurs when one parent record or field has either zero or one child record only. These relationships are the easiest to represent in databases because both the parent and child records may be in the same table.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/#

Comment: tnx of couse,but i wanna now ur opinionabout which method better or maybe i don`t know some one else

Comment: In django, if you want to create more than 'password' or 'password_confirm' you should use the forms available in django to familiarize yourself first, django contains many different forms, get used to that before you want to do more .

'Onetoone' is a relationship in the database, if you want the best for the user, you should use 'foreign keys' to connect the database instead of 'onetoone'